# App crashing when added content provider in update

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have an working android app but it fails when i have added content provider in it. 
It is crashing at first run because and showing that table not found which is a part of ContentProvider

`Please suggest me How we can solve this while working with content provider.`
I am aware of this fact while we need to solve same with sqlite that it is crashing because the database structure is changed from previous version to this phase 2 version.  You need to handle the DB update in the app software explicitly.

```
DashboardActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tbl_dragPosition (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT left_pos, orientation, top_pos FROM tbl_dragPosition
W/System.err( 9512): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2366)
W/System.err( 9512): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
W/System.err( 9512): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
W/System.err( 9512): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
W/System.err( 9512): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
W/System.err( 9512): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
W/System.err( 9512): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5322)
W/System.err( 9512): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 9512): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err( 9512): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
W/System.err( 9512): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
W/System.err( 9512): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err( 9512): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tbl_dragPosition (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT left_pos, orientation, top_pos FROM tbl_dragPosition

W/dalvikvm( 9512): threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
I/dalvikvm( 9512): +++ calling Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;.uncaughtException
E/AndroidRuntime( 9512): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

Comment: You already mention that the DB update is wrong. So why don't you show that code?

Comment: @CL. I was not having any database in phase 1 but in phase 2. Is this again related with update  ?

Comment: Well, the error message shows that you do *not* have a complete database. Show the code that should create the database.

Comment: @CL. please see class i have used to create content provider http://paste.ofcode.org/QNjPTTyTBsnfaiKZdPVjJh